# Logs for Azure Storage account SFTP service?

Tags: azure, logging, sftp, azure-storage-account

Can we get logs from the Azure SFTP service in Storage account? I've enabled the SFTP feature in the storage account which works as an SFTP service, I'm able to push files into it using client apps like Filezilla and Win SCP. But it's not working when I'm trying to push files from a client app. Client app is a reporting system which has the ability to push reports into an SFTP server.

My intention is to check the logs for the SFTP service and see why it's not serving requests from the client app

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If the client can't reach the server for whatever reason, having logs on the Azure side won't help in any way. Check the client logs. What error are you getting?

Here's a list of common issues that might help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-known-issues

Answer (score 0):

You can activate logs on your storage account from the diagnostic settings.

Go to the sftp storage account resource, then from the side menu you will see:

[image]

From it select the storage type (blob for example) you can then add a diagnostic settings:

[image]

Then select the category and select to which ever destination you desire, for example you can map it to a log analytic resource

[image]

Then you can query the logs, for example:

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where Category contains "StorageWrite"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the logs in the storage account from Monitoring -> Diagnostic settings then choose which resource you want to get logs for.

Answer (score -1):

As per this current [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-known-issues#integrations), you can pull the sftp logs by applying the filters in the activity logs or by enabling diagnostic settings on the storage accounts.

[image]

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-known-issues#troubleshooting) documentation , for more information about the know issues with SFTP protocol in Azure blob storage account & currently this feature is in preview.